# Why the change in language when warning about the plagues?

Tags: parshanut-torah-comment, plagues-makkos, bo, va-eira

I noticed an interesting change in the language Moses uses when warning Pharoah about plagues:

- Dam - [Shemot 7:17](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=9596&st=&pgnum=94) "Thus said G-d"
- Tzefarde'ah - [Shemot 7:26](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=9596&st=&pgnum=98) "Thus said G-d"
- Arov - [Shemot 8:16](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=9596&st=&pgnum=106) "Thus said G-d"
- Dever - [Shemot 9:1](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=9596&st=&pgnum=110) "Thus said G-d, the G-d of the Hebrews"
- Barad - [Shemot 9:13](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=9596&st=&pgnum=112) "Thus said G-d, the G-d of the Hebrews"
- Arbeh - [Shemot 10:3](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=9596&st=&pgnum=126) "Thus said G-d, the G-d of the Hebrews"
- Bechorot [Shemot 11:4](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=9596&st=&pgnum=140&hilite=) "Thus said G-d"

Why the change of the phrasing? Is there something particular about those plagues that it says "G-d of the Hebrews"?

I'm aware that those plagues, the Torah mentions that it did not affect the Hebrews. Perhaps, this is why that phrase is mentioned. However, I don't think blood or frogs affected them, either.

Comment: http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14488&st=&pgnum=37&hilite=

Comment: @GershonGold I viewed your source. But, I'm not quite following what sections answer my question. Is there something there that you can compile into an answer? If not, I may have to start a bounty.